# Java Secure Websocket - Load SSL context from TLS cert file and connect to WSS URI

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, java-websocket

I'm looking for a way to load a TLS cert file (`ssl_cert_auth_params`) that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
****************************************************************
************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In a Java WSS (Secure WebSocket) client.

I can easily setup the `ssl_context` in python with this:

```
import ssl
import pathlib

ssl_context   = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
localhost_pem = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "../../folder/ssl_cert_auth_params"
ssl_context.load_verify_locations(localhost_pem)
```

And connect to WSS uri with this:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect_to_uri(uri, ssl_context):
    ws = await websockets.connect(uri, ssl=ssl_context, ping_interval=3)
    return (ws)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ws = loop.run_until_complete(connect_to_uri(uri, ssl_context))
```

but I cannot find an easy way to do the same with a **java wss client library**.

Comment: which java wss client library are you planning to use?

Comment: at this moment one that works easily for this purpose, when I'll have more options I'll choose, suggestions are gladly accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a websocket expert but here is a snippet which should do the trick for you in java with WebSockets for Jetty:

I used the following libraries:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
   <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
   <version>9.4.41.v20210516</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
   <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart-for-jetty</artifactId>
   <version>6.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And the Java code:

```java
import nl.altindag.ssl.SSLFactory;
import nl.altindag.ssl.util.CertificateUtils;
import nl.altindag.ssl.util.JettySslUtils;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class WebSocketExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
                .withTrustMaterial(CertificateUtils.loadCertificate(Paths.get("/path/to/certificate.pem")))
                .build();

        var sslContextFactory = JettySslUtils.forClient(sslFactory);
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
        var webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(httpClient);
        webSocketClient.start();

        var session = webSocketClient.connect(new MyWebSocketListener(), new URI("ws://echo.websocket.org")).get();
        session.getRemote().sendString("Hello there!");
    }

    private static class MyWebSocketListener implements WebSocketListener {

        @Override
        public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] bytes, int i, int i1) {
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void onWebSocketText(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onWebSocketClose(int i, String s) {
            System.out.println("closed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
            System.out.println("connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onWebSocketError(Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("got error");
        }
    }

}
```

Jetty SslContextFactory does not have a function which will directly read and use the pem files. So you would end up adding logic to read the pem file and map it into a KeyStore object and then supply it to a TrustManager and then create a SSLContext from it. Therefore I suggest my own library to hide away the verbosity. I hope you like it :)

Comment: Nice! And normally I can use for a "wss://" endpoint URI too, correct? As soon as I can correctly test with my end point in the next weeks I'll come back to accept this if no other better answers are provided. Thank you!

Comment: Yes I tried the example wss link to an URI and it worked. However I could not test the SSL part as I have no secured wss server. So I would love to hear your results

Comment: @madx any updates from your side, have you been able to try it out with ssl?